# Externalize template from heredoc

Tags: bash, templates, heredoc

How can I externalize the template part of a "heredoc"?

I have a bash script that uses a "heredoc" to write data to a file:

```
foo=bar

data=$(cat <<EOF
foo: $foo
EOF
)

echo $data
```

When executing this script, I see the expected `foo: bar`.

Now, I would like to pull out the template part from the script to support multiple output formats using different template files. For example, a `template.properties` file containing just:

```
foo: $foo
```

For this reason I modified the script:

```
foo=bar

template=$(cat template.properties)

data=$(cat <<EOF
$template
EOF
)

echo $data
```

The problem I am having is that the `$foo` variable never gets evaluated, i.e. the above code prints out `foo: $foo` instead of the desired `foo: bar`.

Comment: You need to evaluate the content of `template.properties`, for that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `cat` (kill the cat!) and you don't need the here-doc either.  Unfortunately you do need `eval`:

```
foo=bar

read -r template < template.properties

eval data="\"$template\""

echo $data
```

`eval` is often referred to as "evil" because it can pose a security risk.  Any malicious command, or error, could be inserted and executed.  It is usually best to avoid embedding code like this.

Why not write the template so you just `source` it?  For example, make the template:

```
data=$foo
```

and your code:

```
foo=bar

source template.properties
echo $data
```

Comment: Thanks. Sourcing the template is a good idea, but I also need to support other data formats such as JSON, e.g. `{"foo": "$foo"}`.

Comment: You might be better off using something like `python` which comes bundled with a JSON module and supports many other data formats as well.